# Running uvicorn from subfolder results in ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, module, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to run a FastAPI instance in a subfolder using uvicorn, but for some reason I don't quite grasp it's causing a ModuleNotFoundError.

The following is a minimal example:
My file structure is:

- Project

  - Subfolder

    - main.py

main.py contains the following code:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('subfolder.main:app')
```

When I run it from pycharm by clicking the green play arrow beside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` it seems to start up fine, but if I try to run it from the command line in the project folder using `python subfolder/main.py` I end up getting
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subfolder'"

I've tried adding a __init__.py file in subfolder to make it a python module, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I have never had a great grasp on python modules and the init folder, and this problem has been bugging me for a while. All of my research seems to be about correctly formatting the uvicorn.run() string and making sure it's guarded with the if main statement, so I'm not sure where to go. Any advice on how to fix this (or even better!) what causes it would be very much appriciated!

Comment: `python subfolder/main.py` When you run the code this way, `subfolder` is the current module directory, and so the code can't find `subfolder.main` because it's _already_ in the `subfolder` directory.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you! That is (of course) exactly what was happening and changing to uvicorn.run('main:app') works just fine. My intuition was that the current directory would be either the project head or the location the python command was run, but I usually just run things through my IDE; Thanks again for teaching me something new.